# Minimum value function

Tags: functions, absolute-value

It's just a very simple question, is there a function defined and that tells you the minumum and maximum value of a list of variables, like:
min(4, 3) = 3
min(2, 19) = 2
max(1, 10, 3) = 10
Is that the way to write it? or is there a accepted way of doing it?
I'm just a high-schooler and I like playing with math sometimes and I wanted to know if there's a more formal way of writing min() and max(), so don't get mad if it's a very obvious thing to you. Thanks.

Comment: $$\max(a,b) = \frac{a + b + |b - a|}{2} \qquad{} \min(a,b) = \frac{a + b - |b - a|}{2}.$$
For more than two arguments, compose, rinse, repeat.

Comment: $\min(a,b)$ and $\max(a,b)$ are indeed important standard functions.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for all the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to answer this question:

---

**Answer 1: (This was given by Nitin in the comments)**

We can write

$$\min(a,b) = \frac{a+b - |b-a|}{2}$$
and
$$\max(a,b) = \frac{a+b + |b-a|}{2}$$

To where this first expression comes from, observe that if $b \ge a$, then $|b-a| = b-a$, so $\frac{a+b - |b-a|}{2} = \frac{a+b - (b-a)}{2} = a$, and if $b < a$, then $|b-a| = a-b$, so $\frac{a+b - |b-a|}{2} = \frac{a+b + (b-a)}{2} = b$.  To get the second expression, notice that $\min(a,b) + \max(a,b) = a+b$, then rearrange and solve for $\max(a,b)$.  If we want to take the maximum over larger (finite) sets of real numbers, we can use the identities

$$\min(a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n) = \min(\min(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n-1}), a_n)$$
$$\max(a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n) = \max(\max(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n-1}), a_n)$$

---

**Answer 2:**

The expressions $\min$ and $\max$ are *already* well defined functions.  Many people get the idea in high school that a function is something that you can write out a 'rule' or 'formula' for, but this isn't correct.  The definition of a function is an object which takes an input and returns an output (this can be made precise using set-theoretic ideas).  The functions $\min$ and $\max$ take as input pairs of (real) numbers (or, if you like, nonempty sets of real numbers), and return the smallest/largest number in the pair (set), respectively.

Comment: You need to be a bit careful saying you can give the functions a nonempty set of read numbers, as such a set does not necessarily have a minimum/maximum, but might only have an infimum/supremum. You could solve this by, for example, imposing compactness (which will guarantee both, but is not necessary for only one to exist). For finite sets though, it's all good, and you gave a good answer, so +1 from me.